# AppleScript/OSAKit/Cocoa Inter-Application Communication Memory Leak

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-leaks, applescript

I have an app that supports various AppleScript commands and I'm running into a memory leak issue when passing a `list` (array) object from a script into the app. There isn't a ton a 100% clear and helpful documentation on adding AppleScript support to your cocoa app, so I'm hoping this is just a simple oversight/error on my part and someone can help me find it.

My end goal is to have another Cocoa app compile and run the script via `OSAKit` but I've also tested using macOS's *Script Editor.app* to pass in a `list` and my main Cocoa app still leaks when doing it that way too:

```
-- This AppleScript command causes leaks
tell application "MyApp"
    update database with things {"thing1", "thing2", "thing3"}
end tell
```

In my other Cocoa app (not the main Cocoa app), I run the above via `OSAKit` but it leaks there as well:

```
 #import <OSAKit/OSAKit.h>

 OSAScript *script= [[OSAScript alloc] initWithSource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tell application \"MyApp\"\nupdate database with things %@", listOfThings]];
 NSDictionary * errorDict = nil;
 NSAppleEventDescriptor *returnDescriptor = [script executeAndReturnError: &errorDict];
```

On the receiving end, my main Cocoa app has an `NSScriptCommand` class set up and can receive and respond to AppleScript commands without any other known issues. Here's what it looks like just for the `list` part:

**MyScriptHandler.h**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyScriptHandler : NSScriptCommand

- (NSAppleEventDescriptor *) performDefaultImplementation;

@end
```

**MyScriptHandler.m**

```
#import "MyScriptHandler.h"

@implementation MyScriptHandler

- (NSAppleEventDescriptor *) performDefaultImplementation
{
    NSString* cmdName = [[self commandDescription] commandName];

    if ([cmdName isEqualToString: @"update database"])
    {
        // GET THE LIST AND PASS IT OFF TO APP DELEGATE FOR PROCESSING
        NSMutableArray *things = [[self evaluatedArguments] valueForKey:@"things"];
        [(AppDelegate *)[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate] updateDatabaseFromAppleScript:options];
    }
    
    return  [NSAppleEventDescriptor descriptorWithBoolean:YES];
}
```

Not sure this is helpful, but my main Cocoa app's AppleScript dictionary (.sdef) looks like this for the command:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE dictionary SYSTEM "file://localhost/System/Library/DTDs/sdef.dtd">

<dictionary title="MyApp Terminology">

    <suite name="MyApp Suite" code="MyAp" description="Commands for MyApp">
        
        <command name="update database" code="MyApUpDB" description="Update the database">
            <parameter name="with things" code="optn" type="list of text" optional="yes" description="">
                <cocoa key="things"/>
            </parameter>
            <cocoa class="MyScriptHandler"/>
        </command>
        
    </suite>￼
    
</dictionary>
```

Thank you in advance for any help!
[image]

Comment: Looking this and your answer over, I think the problem was in your sdef, here: `type="list of text"`. That's not proper sdef format (and I'm surprised it worked at all). Proper format would be two key-value pairs: `type="text" list="yes"`I'm guessing you're memory leak happens because the app is expecting a *text* descriptor from the event manager (it just ignores the 'list of' part and sees 'text'), but is receiving a *list* descriptor. It's somehow managing the conversion, but creating the leak in the process.

Comment: @TedWrigley Thanks so much for your comment. This is really helpful information and I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have fixed the memory leak issue by making the following changes...

In my .sdef file, I changed the parameter type for the command to be `type="record"` instead of `type="list of text"`. This means I have to pass some useless/duplicate information (the key name) into my main app, but that's acceptable since it's now not leaking and doesn't cost any extra CPU as far as I can tell.

```
    <command name="update database" code="MyApUpDB" description="Update the database">
        <parameter name="with things" code="optn" type="record" optional="yes" description="">
            <cocoa key="things"/>
        </parameter>
        <cocoa class="MyScriptHandler"/>
    </command>
```

Then, I updated the AppleScript to pass a `record` instead of a `list`:

```
-- This AppleScript command does NOT cause leaks
tell application "MyApp"
    update database with things {thing1:"thing1", thing2:"thing2", thing3:"thing3"}
end tell
```